# Declaration of Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader::getRemoteContents(...) on Heruko

Tags: symfony, heroku

We've started today to get an error during the builds on Herko.

```
- Installing symfony/flex (v1.0.67): Loading from cache
   Plugin installation failed, rolling back
     - Removing symfony/flex (v1.0.67)


     [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     Declaration of Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader::getRemoteContents($originUrl, $fileUrl, $context) should be compatible with Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem::getRemoteContents($originUrl, $fileUrl, $context, ?array &$responseHeaders = NULL)
```

From Googling (https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/397) I've tried updating the flex version by just updating the composer.json to `"symfony/flex": "1.0.89",` then pushing the code GitHub, which then intern triggers the build on Herko, but I keep getting the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing composer.json, you should run `composer update` to update your composer.lock file, then commit & push.